# What else can be optimized how to use JTextField default text prompt function

Tags: java

What else can be optimized how to use JTextField default text prompt function
Thank you all for your answers

---

=============================================================================

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;[enter image description here][1]
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class WindowActionEvent extends JFrame {
    JTextField text;
    JTextArea textShow;
    JButton button;
    ReaderListen listener;

    public WindowActionEvent() throws HeadlessException {
        init();
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    void init() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        text = new JTextField(10);
        button = new JButton("读取");
        textShow = new JTextArea(25,50);
        textShow.setEditable(false);
        listener = new ReaderListen();
        listener.setJTextField(text);
        listener.setJTextArea(textShow);
        text.addActionListener(listener);
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        add(text);
        add(button);
        add(new JScrollPane(textShow));
    }
}


class ReaderListen implements ActionListener {
    JTextField text;
    JTextArea textShow;

    public void setJTextField(JTextField text) {
        this.text = text;
    }



    public void setJTextArea(JTextArea textShow) {
        this.textShow = textShow;
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {
            File file = new File(text.getText()); //getDocument()
            FileReader inOne = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader inTwo = new BufferedReader(inOne);
            String s = null;
            while ((s = inTwo.readLine()) != null) {
                textShow.append(s+"\n");
            }
            inOne.close();
            inTwo.close();
        } catch (Throwable e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
public class Matematiktest extends WindowActionEvent {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WindowActionEvent win = new WindowActionEvent();
        win.setBounds(100,100,1000,500);
        win.setTitle("处理ActionEvent事件");
    }
}
```

This is the code I checked about the default text prompt function of JTextField but I don’t know where it should be placed or used

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
 
import javax.swing.JTextField;
 
public class JTextFieldHintListener implements FocusListener {
    private String hintText;
    private JTextField textField;
    public JTextFieldHintListener(JTextField jTextField,String hintText) {
        this.textField = jTextField;
        this.hintText = hintText;
        jTextField.setText(hintText);  //默认直接显示
        jTextField.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    }
 
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        //获取焦点时，清空提示内容
        String temp = textField.getText();
        if(temp.equals(hintText)) {
            textField.setText("");
            textField.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        
    }
 
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {   
        //失去焦点时，没有输入内容，显示提示内容
        String temp = textField.getText();
        if(temp.equals("")) {
            textField.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
            textField.setText(hintText);
        }
        
    }
 
}
```

Comment: This is a very vague question and I'm not even sure what you're asking about. Please read [ask] and either state a problem you're trying to solve, what you tried and why you failed, or, if this  is more about getting a review, post the question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *I don’t know where it should be placed or used* - you use it AFTER you create your JTextField since you need a reference to the text field in order to create an instance of the class. See: [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) for a different implementation.